# Compare generic types from a collection to the same type java

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        Box<String> box = null;
        List<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            box = new Box<>(scanner.nextLine());
            boxes.add(box);
        }
        box = new Box<>(scanner.nextLine());
        Box.count(boxes, box);
    }
```

I am creating the boxes here and i am passing them to a static method in the box class

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T name;

    public Box(T name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static <E> int count(List<E> list, E compeer) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (E el : list) {
            if (el.compearTo(compeer) < 0) { // ofc it doesnt works compearTo is red caus i am not extending Comperable
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

In the box count method i have to count how many elements are "lower" then the 2nd argument of the method, but i cant compear anything in there... I know that the Generic type has to extend Comperable `<E extends Comparable>` for that to happen, but if I type  `<E extends Comparable>` in my `Box.count` method then i cant pass the arguments.

Comment: i cant compear i have compile time error

Comment: Of course. You want to compare Box instances, but Box instances are not comparable, and your method doesn't accept a custom Comparator. BTW, Why do you have a method that is completely unrelated to Box in the Box class? And what is the point of this class in the first place? Why don't you just use Strings and a List<String> directly?

Comment: How do i make my method eccept a custom Comparator to compear the boxes? Why am i having the method there? I am trying to learn generics. Can you show me how can i compear them i this case?

Comment: What exactly is the input on which your program is working?

Comment: Well, you add a third argument of type Comparator<? super E>, and use it inside the method to count the elements that, according to this comparator, are lower than compeer.

Comment: Also, since you're learning generics: don't use raw types. Your list should be of type List<Box<String>>, not List<Box>.

Comment: Box<String> box = null so i am doing the same thing all boxes in the list are string boxes

Comment: Surely you'd need the list elements to implement `Comparable`. So, declare the type variable as `<E extends Comparable<E>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if I type  `<E extends Comparable>` in my Box.count method then i cant pass the arguments.

The reason why you can't pass the arguments is because `Box` does not implement `Comparable`.

What you should do instead is add the generic constraint in the `Box` class:

```
class Box<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

Also, your `count` method is a bit *too* generic. It will probably make more sense if `compeer`'s type is changed to `Box<T>` and `list` to `List<Box<T>>`.

The method signature now looks like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int count(List<Box<T>> list, Box<T> compeer) {
```

And you can implement the method like this:

```
return (int)list.stream().
    filter(x -> x.name.compareTo(compeer.name) < 0).count();
```

Comment: @ВсеЕдно you should not be using raw types for your list. Change the list's type to `List<Box<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

Box doesn't need to be a generic class as you use a specific type only according to the call to the static method, not according to the class.
It is misleading to specify it.
You pass a string in Box constructor, so provide a String argument seems finer.

> In the box count method i have to count how many elements are "lower"
>   then the 2nd argument of the method.

Then make your `E` type declaration in your static method inherit Comparable in order to be able to compare each element of the List between.
Box should also implement Comparable and it is fine.

And so you could compare elements in this way.
If the passed element is higher than the current iterated element, increment the counter :

```
 if (compeer.compareTo(currentElement)>1){
    counter++;
 }
```

It could give that :

```
public class Box implements Comparable<Box> {

    private String name;

    public Box(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Box o) {
          /// your rule to compare Box elements
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int count(List<E> list, E compeer) {
        int counter = 0;

        if (compeer==null){
            return 0;
        }
        for (E currentElement : list){
            if (compeer.compareTo(currentElement)==1){
               counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works, but whats the difference between`E extends Comparable<E>` and`E extends Comparable` can you give me something to read on it

Comment: You are welcome. `Comparable` is a generic class. So using it without specifying the type means using a raw type. As a consequence you will have to override the `compareTo()` method with an Object as parameter (that is `public int compareTo(Object o)`). As raw types are by default considered as Object at compile time.